# Does freelancing work cause problems for my UK visa

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, proof-provenance-of-funds

I work as a freelancer. I am an online teacher.

I get my payment by western union or to my bank account.

I wanted to know how I can prove the origin of my money in my application. 
I applied for a short term visa and it was refused because I didn’t put the origin of my money.

Comment: Freelancing work has caused problems for UK visas. Many examples on here.